# How to pull updates to a branch from master without having them on my commit history?

Tags: git

I made a pull request long back and in the meantime there have been some updates in the master branch. If I simply run `git rebase master` then all the new commits from master appear in the commit history of this branch. How to update my PR without having the updated commit history from master in this branch?

My PR has 2 commits and the master branch has around 10 new commits. If I run the above mentioned command then my PR gets a total of 12 commits.

Comment: You want the commits, correct?  You just don't want the history.  Here's a good tutorial (one of many - including many instructive threads here on SO): https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history.  You can also search for "git squash", "git interactive rebase" and similar.  You also need to be cognizant of *WHICH* repo/which branch you wish to change.

Comment: Note that in Git, the commits *are* the history, and the history is the commits. That's what's in the repository: commits. That's all there is, so that's what history is. If you don't like the existing commits, make new and different ones (perhaps using the existing ones to start with).

Answer (score 1):

Get onto your PR branch and merge `master` into it:

```
git switch myPRBranch
git fetch origin master:master
git merge master
```

Resolve any merge conflicts and you're all set.

Doing this is totally normal; in fact, in my organization it is required behavior. If your PR branch lives for longer than few days, it needs to have `main` merged into it (every few days). Otherwise you can end up with a horror when the time comes to merge the PR branch.